# How to Optimise SQL Query due to Slow Performance?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, optimization

I am looking for some help in regards to optimising the following query due to slow performance. The tables and records do not exist on my machine (helping a friend) hence I do not have the insert records and all I know is that the tables are large and contain millions of rows of data. I have been sent the create statements in order to show the table relationships with the foreign keys etc.

The following is the query:

```
SELECT
    tutor.tutor_id, 
    tutor.subject_id,
    course.title,
    SUBSTR(score.date, 4, 2) AS month,
    AVG(score.score)
FROM
    tutor
    LEFT JOIN course ON tutor.course_id = course.course_id
    LEFT JOIN score ON tutor.course_id = score.course_id
WHERE
    course.course_id IS NOT NULL
    AND score.date > '01-MAR-2020' 
    AND score.student_id in (SELECT student_id FROM students)
GROUP BY 
    tutor.tutor_id, 
    tutor.subject_id,
    course.title,
    SUBSTR(score.date, 4, 2)
    ;
```

Having looked through the above query, I understand that, there is a sub select query within the where clause that could be slowing the query down and this would be first step to changeover to an  INNER JOIN.

I am trying to think of what else I could do, to quicken the query such as selecting the fields (which it already has). Only other thing would be to add a LIMIT to sample query results (can't run this to test myself) and also add an EXPLAIN PLAN to understand what's causing the delays in the results coming back so slow. The other option is to check if the columns in the joins have been indexed.

CREATE STATEMENTS

```
CREATE TABLE Score (
    score_id integer,
    student_id integer,
    course_id integer,
    date date,
    score integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(score_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES Students(student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_id) REFERENCES Course(course_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Student (
    student_id integer,
    first_name varchar,
    last_name varchar,
    group_id integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(group_id) REFERENCES Groups(group_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Groups (
    group_id integer,
    name varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY(group_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Course (
    course_id integer,
    title varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY(course_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Tutor (
    course_id integer,
    tutor_id integer,
    group_id integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(tutor_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_id) REFERENCES Course(course_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(group_id) REFERENCES Groups(group_id)
);
```

I would appreciate it, if somebody could help me understand, if I have missed anything or if I am along the right lines in trying to optimise the query that I have.

Comment: I think `INNER JOINING` `tutor`, `course`, `score` AND `student` would solve most of your performance issues. So you are along the right lines

Comment: is it true that you do not have any indexes on the involved tables? As far as I can see, both LEFT JOINs are, de-facto, INNER JOINS. And please specify RDBMS you use, because Oracle optimization is not the same as MySQL

Comment: Without execution plan and description of the indexes in on the table, you could always all the hing /*+ PARALLEL(4) */ and it should consume more resources, but improve the performance timewise.

Comment: Hi, thanks everyone, forgot to mention the RDBMS I am using is Oracle.

Comment: Also in regards to the indexes, at present, I am not sure if they are.

Comment: You can check that, just see what you have in all_indexes for these tables.

Comment: @VvdL they are already inner joins because non-null conditions are defined in the `where` clause for `course` and `score`.

Comment: `AND score.student_id in (SELECT student_id FROM students)` does nothing but confirm the existing foreign key between `score` and `students`. It's the same thing as `and score.student_id is not null`. With any luck the optimiser already knows that and does not actually perform the redundant semi-join.

Comment: So changing this in query to a JOIN won't really improve performance?@WilliamRobertson

Comment: @MichaelOwen I wouldn't expect it to make any difference, because the optimiser will already have detected that it can't perform the requested outer join and converted it to inner. Also I would not expect indexes to help, since you want to aggregate all data for the last two years. Indexes are usually best for looking up specific values.

Comment: As others have pointed out, there’s a number of obvious improvements, however Oracle is able to transform the query for you, including placing the group by like what is suggested in an answer. First step should be to get the execution plan that it’s using and identifying where the time is going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You query does not use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as, in the `WHERE` filter, `score.date > '01-MAR-2020'` and `course.course_id IS NOT NULL` can never match `NULL` values so the `OUTER` joined rows will be eliminated.
- Given that then `WHERE  course.course_id IS NOT NULL` is redundant as the join clause `ON tutor.course_id = course.course_id` also enforces the `NOT NULL` condition.
- `'01-MAR-2020'` is not a date; it is a string literal that looks like a date and relies on the SQL engine performing an implicit cast from string-to-date. Use `DATE '2020-03-01'` instead.
- `score.student_id in (SELECT student_id FROM students)` is enforced by the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. You don't need to query the `students` table, you only need to check that the value is `NOT NULL`.
- `SUBSTR(score.date, 4, 2)` relies on an implicit date-to-string conversion. Either use `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM score.date)` to directly get the month number (if you want to group 2022-03 with 2020-03) or use `TRUNC(score.date, 'MM')` (if 2020-03 should not be grouped with 2021-03).

Which makes your query:

```
SELECT tutor.tutor_id, 
       tutor.subject_id,
       course.title,
       TRUNC(score.date, 'MM') AS month,
       AVG(score.score)
FROM   tutor
       INNER JOIN course ON tutor.course_id = course.course_id
       INNER JOIN score  ON tutor.course_id = score.course_id
WHERE  score.date > DATE '2020-03-01' 
AND    score.student_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
       tutor.tutor_id, 
       tutor.subject_id,
       course.title,
       TRUNC(score.date, 'MM');
```

---

As for optimisations:

You can try aggregating the score before joining the other tables:

```
SELECT  t.tutor_id,
        t.subject_id,
        c.title,
        s.month,
        s.avg_score
FROM    ( SELECT course_id,
                 TRUNC(date, 'MM') AS month,
                 AVG(score) AS avg_score
          FROM   score
          WHERE  date > DATE '2020-03-01'
          AND    student_id IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY
                 course_id,
                 TRUNC(date, 'MM')
        ) s
        INNER JOIN tutor t  ON t.course_id = s.course_id
        INNER JOIN course c ON c.course_id = s.course_id
```

This means that you are aggregating by the primary key `course_id` and not by `course.title`. But that is probably a good thing as aggregating by title would combine two different courses that happen to have the same name; which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks MT0, love the explanations and the breakdown of how you worked through that.